# Locally measured angle between two 4-vectors

Tags: general-relativity, vectors

(I am aware of thet [Angle between two 4D vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267817/angle-between-two-4d-vectors)  quesion, this is different.)

I have an observer at some fixed radius away from a Schwarzschild black hole. It emits a photon at some angle $\alpha$ to the outward radial direction (with $0<\alpha<\pi/2$), which has some 4-vector.

How do I relate the 4-vector of the photon to the angle? I would like to have an expression, probably involving the metric and the 4-vector itself, to be equal to some function of the angle.

---

My approach: I think I should contract the 4-vector with a 4-vector of a photon which is radially emitted using the metric. But then I don't know what the result is equal to, so this didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "relate the 4-vector of the photon to the angle"?

Comment: I added the "I would like to have an expression, probably involving the metric and the 4-vector itself, to be equal to some function of the angle" sentence, does it make it clearer?